# Delegates: Predicate vs. Action vs. Func

Tags: c#, delegates, predicate, func

Can someone provide a good explanation (hopefully with examples) of these 3 most important delegates:

- Predicate
- Action
- Func

Answer (score 199, accepted):

- `Predicate`: essentially `Func<T, bool>`; asks the question "does the specified argument satisfy the condition represented by the delegate?" Used in things like List.FindAll.
- `Action`: Perform an action given the arguments. Very general purpose. Not used much in LINQ as it implies side-effects, basically.
- `Func`: Used *extensively* in LINQ, usually to transform the argument, e.g. by projecting a complex structure to one property.

Other important delegates:

- `EventHandler`/`EventHandler<T>`: Used all over WinForms
- `Comparison<T>`: Like `IComparer<T>` but in delegate form.

Comment: There's also `System.Converter<TInput, TOutput>`, though it's rarely used.

Comment: The Converter is a nice delegate when a lot of Converting of Model into Business classes is needed, i.e. http://www.stum.de/2009/12/23/using-a-converter-to-convert-from-a-model-to-a-business-class/

Comment: `EventHandler/EventHandler<T>` appear all over outside of WinForms too.

Comment: @Andy: Somewhat... But less so in WPF for example. I agree that there's nothing WinForms-specific to it.

Answer (score 75):

`Action`, `Func` and `Predicate` all belong to the delegate family.

`Action` : Action can take n input parameters but it returns void.

`Func` : Func can take n input parameters but it will always return the result of the provided type. `Func<T1,T2,T3,TResult>`, here T1,T2,T3 are input parameters and TResult is the output of it.

`Predicate` : Predicate is also a form of Func but it will always return bool. In simple words it is wrapper of `Func<T,bool>`.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to Jon's answer, there is also

- `Converter<TInput, TOutput>`: It's essentially `Func<TInput, TOutput>`, but with semantics. Used by List.ConvertAll and Array.ConvertAll, but personally haven't seen it anywhere else.

Answer (score 9):

A simple example about the arguments and what retutn each type

This Func take two int arguments and return an int.Func always has return type

```
 Func<int, int, int> sum = (a, b) => a + b;
 Console.WriteLine(sum(3, 5));//Print 8
```

In this case func doesn't have arguments but return a string

```
Func<string> print = () => "Hello world";
Console.WriteLine(print());//Print Hello world
```

This Action take two int arguments and return void

```
Action<int, int> displayInput = (x, y) => Console.WriteLine("First number is :" + x + " , Second number is "+ y);
displayInput(4, 6); //Print First number is :4 , Second number is :6
```

This Predicate take one argument and always return bool.Generally Predicates always return bool.

```
Predicate<int> isPositive = (x) => x > 0;
Console.WriteLine(isPositive(5));//Print True
```

Answer (score 8):

[`Predicate<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) was introduced in .NET 2.0 with the introduction of generics. It's a delegate taking one parameter and returning a `bool`.

However, with the introduction of LINQ in .NET 3.5, a need was identified for two *families* of generic types - [`Func`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) (the difference being on whether they return anything) taking up to <strike>16</strike> 4<sup>1</sup> generic input parameters and being generic in their return types. If `Func` had existed first, `Predicate<T>` would never have been created in the first place. It's an unnecessarily specialized delegate type.

For backwards compatibility reasons though, they cannot now *remove* `Predicate<T>` from the framework. *Some* may argue that its name does convey specific semantic meaning but I'd struggle to identify many situations where any `Func<T,bool>` (or `Func<T1,T2,bool>`, etc.) wouldn't be considered a predicate.

---

<sup>1</sup>4 in .NET 3.5, 16 in .NET 4 and later.

Comment: AFAIK, .NET 3.5 only introduced variants taking up to 4 parameters.

Comment: @PetSerAl - corrected and footnoted.

Answer (score 5):

## `Action`

Documentation:

> Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and does not return a value.

Functions passed using the `Action` type must return `void`, and can accept from 0 to 16 parameters.
`Action` is commonly used when you want a function that can *use* each element in a container for *something*, or as callbacks.

```cs
public void DoSomething(List<string> lines, Action<string> action)
{
    foreach (string str in lines)
    {
        action(str);
    }
}
```

## `Func`

Documentation:

> Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and returns a value of the type specified by the TResult parameter.

Functions passed using the `Func` type accept from 0 to 16 parameters, and return any type that isn't `void`.
`Func` is commonly used when you want a function that can *modify* or perform some kind of operation on each element in a container.

```cs
//                                                 Parameter Types
//                                                     ▼▼▼  ▼▼▼
public List<int> DoMath(List<(int, int)> numbers, Func<int, int, int> operation)
//                                                               ▲▲▲
//                                                           Return Type
{
    List<int> results = new();
    foreach (var (left, right) in numbers)
    {
        out.Add(operation(left, right));
    }
    return out;
}
```

## `Predicate`

Documentation:

> Represents the method that defines a set of criteria and determines whether the specified object meets those criteria.

Functions passed with the `Predicate` type must return a `bool`, and must accept exactly `1` parameter.

An example of functions that accept *Predicates* are LINQ functions like `All` & `Any`, which return true if the supplied predicate returns true for *all*/*any* of the elements in a list.

```cs
public void Example(string str)
{
    // The char.IsLetter() function can be used as a predicate
    //   because it takes 1 char as a parameter, and returns a bool.
    //          ▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼
    if (str.All(char.IsLetter))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("All characters in the string are letters.");
    }
}
```

## Comparison

| **Type** | **Return Type** | **Min Parameters** | **Max Parameters** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `Action` | `void` | `0` | `16` |
| `Func` | **Any type that isn't** `void` | `0` | `16` |
| `Predicate` | `bool` | `1` | `1` |

The only differences between `Action`, `Func`, and `Predicate` are the types that they return & accept as parameters; they are all delegates and as such they all represent a function passed as a parameter.

You can make your own `delegate` types in 1 line of code, and use them in the same way as the premade ones.

```cs
//         Accepts functions that return a decimal type, and...
//              ▼▼▼▼▼▼▼
public delegate decimal Operation(decimal left, decimal right);
//                                ▲▲▲▲▲▲▲       ▲▲▲▲▲▲▲
//                    ...take 2 parameters, both of type decimal.
```

You can read more about delegates here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/

Answer (score 4):

MethodInvoker is one which WinForms developers may use; it accepts no arguments and returns no results. It predates Action, and is still often used when invoking onto the UI thread since BeginInvoke() et al accept an untyped Delegate; although Action will do just as well.

```
myForm.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
  MessageBox.Show("Hello, world...");
});
```

I'd also be aware of ThreadStart and ParameterizedThreadStart; again most people will substitute an Action these days.

Answer (score 4):

Predicate, Func and Action are inbuilt delegate instances of .NET. Each of these delegate instances could refer or point to user methods with specific signature.

Action delegate - Action delegate instances could point to methods that take arguments and returns void.

Func delegate - Func delegate instance could point to method(s) that take variable number of arguments and return some type.

Predicate - Predicates are similar to func delegate instances and they could point to methods that take variable number of arguments and return a bool type.

Answer (score 2):

Action and Func with lambda:

```
person p = new person();
Action<int, int> mydel = p.add;       /*(int a, int b) => { Console.WriteLine(a + b); };*/
Func<string, string> mydel1 = p.conc; /*(string s) => { return "hello" + s; };*/
mydel(2, 3);
string s1=  mydel1(" Akhil");
Console.WriteLine(s1);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

Func is more LINQ friendly, can be passed in as a parameter. (point-free)

Predicate cannot, has to be wrapped again.

```
Predicate<int> IsPositivePred = i => i > 0;
Func<int,bool> IsPositiveFunc = i => i > 0;

new []{2,-4}.Where(i=>IsPositivePred(i)); //Wrap again

new []{2,-4}.Where(IsPositivePred);  //Compile Error
new []{2,-4}.Where(IsPositiveFunc);  //Func as Parameter
```