# Particulars about Action delegate in C#

Tags: c#, delegates

1) What is the real definition for **Action** delegate? some definitions describe it is as ***polymorphic conditional map*** , some say it  ***Applied decision Table *.**

(*You may ask what will you achieve by knowing definition , if i know it i can understand its real purpose)*.

2) Thanks Binary Worrier,Andrew Hare of stackoverflow for giving nice examples.
    When i declare

```
string[] words = "This is as easy as it looks".Split(' ');
 `Array.ForEach(words, p => Console.WriteLine(p));`
```

i can understand what it actually does.But when i declare ,How does C# interpret when  i 
declare

```
     Dictionary<SomeEnum, Action<User>> methodList =
     new Dictionary<SomeEnum, Action<User>>()
     methodList.Add(SomeEnum.One, DoSomething);
     methodList.Add(SomeEnum.Two, DoSomethingElse);
```

Does it store collections of Actions in dictionary ?.unfortunately as the example was incomplete i did not get it.

3) What is the functional difference between `Action , Function ,Predicate` delagets?

Comment: see answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566860/delegates-predicate-action-func

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's just another delegate. `Action<T>` is declared like this:

```
void Action<T>(T item)
```

It's just "something which acts on a single item". There are generic overloads with more type parameters and normal parameters. In itself, an `Action<T>` isn't an applied decision table or anything like that - it's just a delegate which can do "something" with an item.

The dictionary example is just a dictionary with enum values as keys, and actions as values - so you can look up what to do based on the enum value, and then pass in a `User` reference for it to act on.

As for `Func` vs `Action` vs `Predicate`: `Func` is like `Action`, but returning a value. `Predicate` is similar, but always returns `bool`, and there aren't the range of generic overloads, just `Predicate<T>` to determine if an item "matches" the predicate.

Answer (score 2):

Action, Func and Predicate have different signatures:

void Action<...>(...)
T Func<..., T>(...)
bool Predicate<T>(T)

Action<...> is the same as Func<..., void>
Predicate<T> is the same as Func<T, bool>

Answer (score 2):

1) the Action delegates

```
(Action, Action<T>, Action<T, T2> ...)
```

are general purpose delegate to avoid the creation of to many delegate in your application. The idea is :

```
//- Action    => void method with 0 args
//- Action<T> => void method with 1 arg of type T
//- Action<T, T2> => void method with 2 args of type T et T2
//...
```

2) that dictionary stores for each 'SomeEnum' values, a method wicth match this signature :

```
void MethodExample (User arg);
```

Here is an example :

```
public Init() {
    deleteUserMethodsByStatus = new Dictionary<SomeEnum, Action<User>>();
    deleteUserMethodsByStatus.Add(UserStatus.Active, user => { throw new BusinessException("Cannot delete an active user."); });
    deleteUserMethodsByStatus.Add(UserStatus.InActive, DoUserDeletion});
}

//This is how you could use this dictionary
public void DeleteUser(int userId) {
    User u = DaoFactory.User.GetById(userId);
    deleteUserMethodsByStatus[u.Status](u);
}

//the actual deletion process
protected internal DoUserDeletion(User u) {
    DaoFactory.User.Delete(u);
}
```

3) Difference between Action , Function ,Predicate :
- an action is a void method(no return value)
- a function is a non void method (has a return value)
- a predicate must return a boolean value and take 1 argument (it basically answere yes or no to question that take 1 argument)

I hope this help.

Comment: Absoultely it is very helpful