# Odd Lambda Expression Question

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5, lambda

```
List<string> a = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
List<string> b = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };

b.RemoveAll(a.Contains);
```

If you loop through b it will now only contain d e and f. Can anyone expand out whats actually happening, because currently it doesnt make any sense at all.

Edit: I was more talking about the use of predicates. How does know how to pass what into where?

Comment: Man its hard for me to think like a newbie anymore. This makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: Could be worth mentioning that this snippet wouldn't work prior to .NET 2.0 (and "C# 2.0")... 

The compiler is creating a matching delegate from the a.Contains method. In pre-2.0 mode you would have to create the delegate yourself (new Predicate<string>(a.Contains))

Comment: Well, the List-class didn't exist prior to .NET 2.0 either, but that is besides my point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
b.RemoveAll(<function that takes a string and returns true if we want to remove it>)
```

no lambda expression required.

perhaps you'd like for the line to read

```
b.RemoveAll(x => a.Contains(x))
```

however, the function  `x=> a.Contains(x)`  is simply a function that takes a string and returns a bool indicating whether a contains x. a.Contains is already a function that does that.

Answer (score 5):

The { } Syntax is a collection initializer. The code is equivalent to

```
List<string> a = new List<string>();
a.Add("a");
a.Add("b");
a.Add("c");
List<string> b = new List<string>();
b.Add("a");
b.Add("b");
b.Add("c");
b.Add("d");
b.Add("e");
b.Add("f");
```

b.RemoveAll is a function that calls another function and passes in a string. It's like this:

```
foreach(string s in b) {
    if(FunctionToCall(s) == true) b.Remove(s);
}
```

a.Contains is a function that takes a string and returns a bool. So the code can be changed to:

```
foreach(string s in b) {
    if(a.Contains(s)) b.Remove(s);
}
```

Note that in this Lambda-Syntax, you are passing the "a.Contains" *function* - not the result of the function! It's like a function pointer. RemoveAll *expects* to take a function in the form of "bool FunctionName(string input)".

**Edit:** Do you know what delegates are? They are a bit like function pointers: A delegate specifies a signature ("Takes 2 strings, returns an int"), and then you can use it like a variable. If you don't know about delegates, read [Karl Seguins article](http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2008/11/27/back-to-basics-delegates-anonymous-methods-and-lambda-expressions.aspx).

Some delegates are needed extremely often, so the .net Framework developers added three types of extremely common delegates:

- Predicate: A delegate that takes a T and returns a bool.
- Action: A delegate that takes 1 to 4 parameters and returns void
- Function: A delegate that takes 0 to 4 parameters and returns a T

(Shamelessly copied from Jon Skeet's [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566860/delegates-predicate-action-func))

So predicate is just the name given for a delegate, so that you don't have to specify it yourself.

If you have ANY function in your assembly with the signature

"bool YourFunction(string something)", it is a `Predicate<string>` and can be passed into any other function that takes one:

```
public bool SomeFunctionUsedAsPredicate(string someInput)
{
    // Perform some very specific functionality, i.e. calling a web
    // service to look up stuff in a database and decide if someInput is good
    return true;
}

// This Function is very generic - it does not know how to check if someInput
// is good, but it knows what to do once it has found out if someInput is good or not
public string SomeVeryGenericFunction(string someInput, Predicate<string> someDelegate)
{
    if (someDelegate.Invoke(someInput) == true)
    {
        return "Yup, that's true!";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Nope, that was false!";
    }
}

public void YourCallingFunction()
{
    string result = SomeVeryGenericFunction("bla", SomeFunctionUsedAsPredicate);
}
```

The whole point is separation of concerns (see the comment in SomeGenericFunction) and also to have very generic functions. Look at my [generic, extensible string encoding function](http://www.stum.de/2009/12/28/an-extension-method-to-encode-strings/). This uses the Func rather than the Predicate delegate, but the purpose is the same.

Answer (score 3):

look at it like this:

```
foreach(string s in b)
{
  if(a.Contains(s))
     b.Remove(s);
}
```

You passing the bit in the if evaluation clause as a delegate (managed equivalent of a function pointer). The `RemoveAll` method unrolls the list and does the rest.

Comment: Lambdas are those things with the lambda operator, aka strange arrow: `=>`. `a.Contains` is a method group, and the compiler automagically creates a delegate for it that is of the type expected by RemoveAll (`Predicate<string>`).

Answer (score 2):

It says 'remove all elements in b that are contained in a'.  So you're left only with the one's in b that weren't also present in a.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly expanded version of your code that shows what's happening:

```
 List<string> a = new List<string> () { "a", "b", "c" };
 List<string> b = new List<string> () { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
 Predicate<string> ps = a.Contains;
 b.RemoveAll (ps);
```

Answer (score 0):

For every element in `b`, `a.Contains()` is being evaluated for that element. If it's true, it is removed.

So, you're removing every element from `b` that is also contained in `a`.

The function "`a.Contains`" is being passed as an argument to `RemoveAll`.

Answer (score 0):

The signature for RemoveAll looks like this ...

```
public int RemoveAll(Predicate<T> match);
```

A `Predicate<T>` is a delegate that takes Ts and returns bools ...

```
public delegate bool Predicate<T>(T obj)
```

RemoveAll is thus asking for a reference to a method that will, in your case, take strings and return bools.  `List<T>.Contains` is such a method.  You will note that the signature for `List<T>.Contains` matches the Predicate delegate (it takes Ts and returns bools) ...

```
public bool Contains(T item);
```

RemoveAll will apply whatever Predicate is passed as "match" to each element of the list upon which it is called (b in your case).  So, if `a.Contains("a")`, for example, returns true, then all the a's will be removed from the b list.  Thus, in your example, all the a's, b's and c's are removed.

Using a tool like [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) will let you look at the code of RemoveAll and that might help clarify what's happening under the covers.