# C# Accept Object Parameter via Lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to send an object to a parameter using a lambda expression.

If I have a Settings class like so:

```
public class Settings() {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Whatever {get;set;}
}
```

And some other method whose argument is a Settings class:

```
public object GenerateIt(Settings settings) {
    // stuff here
}
```

I want to call it like so:

```
myObject.GenerateIt(
    s => {
        s.Name = "this";
        s.Whatever = "whatever";
    }
)
```

I've tried this but it doesn't quite do the trick:

```
public object GenerateIt(Func<Settings> settings) { ... }
```

I'm also trying (per current answers) using an Action:

```
public object GenerateIt(Action<Settings> settings) { ... }
```

... which allows me to (apparently) call the method in the way I'd prefer, but I can't seem to find out how to access those settings that I pass in?

```
public object GenerateIt(Action<Settings> settings) {

    Console.WriteLine(settings.Name);   // nope

    var s = settings(); // nope

    ??? 
}
```

(and yes, I did consult the documentation - if it were clear to me after that, I wouldn't still be asking)

What's the correct mechanism to allow for passing the object as indicated in the "I want to call it like so" example?  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the documentation.

`Func<T>` *returns* a `T` and takes no parameters.  You want `Action<T>`.

Comment: please see the question update... how do I then use the setting object from within the target method?

Comment: @jdl134679 you can call it like `var s = new Settings(); settings(s);` and `s` will contain your properties set.

Comment: I see... create a new variable, pass that to the Action, and the action fills the variable accordingly.  That works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
public object GenerateIt(Action<Settings> settings) { ... }
```

Read more on Action, Func, Predictate here:
[Delegates: Predicate Action Func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566860/delegates-predicate-action-func)

Update: Not sure what you are trying to archive, but try this.

[image]

Comment: How do then I use `settings` within the body of that method?  With `Func`, I'd say `Settings s = settings.Invoke()`, then use the `s` variable to access what I passed... can't seem to find how with to do that with an `Action`