# When to use Action Delegate instead of Predicate Delegate

Tags: c#

When would you use a Predicate Delegate over an Action Delegate?

For example, why does `List<string>.RemoveAll()` require a `Predicate<string>` rather than an `Action<string>`? I assume it is because `Action<string>` can only return a `void`. So is the only difference between them the return type of the delegate?

Sorry if this is too vague, I am trying to wrap my head around the nuances and the terms.

Comment: You can read about difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4317479/1997232). And if you still ask "when" question, then answer going to be opinion based. My opinion - never, use `Func<..., bool>` (obviously for void only option is `Action<...>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Predicate delegate as the name says constitutes a *Predicate* which would match a condition/predicate and return `bool`. Where as Action delegate as the signature says doesn't return anything (one way work).

`List<string>.RemoveAll()` requires a predicate cause, what if you want to remove all element `T` from list which matches a specific condition?

Answer (score 1):

They are entirely different - `Action` represents a void function; `Predicate` is an older version of `Func<T, bool>` - a generic function that accepts an object and returns a boolean value. Use depends on need, but it should never be a choice between these two types.

Answer (score -1):

It is beautifully described here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55058355/11100119

Comment: While "configuring things" is _a use case_, `Action` delegates can be used for many purposes. Important aspect is that they represent `void` functions

Comment: @CoolBots yup, i gave an example, ofcourse there are so many implementations