# Difficulty understanding how to pass this void function as a parameter to another function

Tags: c#, function

I am getting lost in the many answers and examples here ([Pass Method as Parameter using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2082615/2287576)) about passing functions.

At the moment I have this:

```
private void AddWeekToHistory(ref XDocument xdoc, MSAHistoryWeek historyWeek)
{
   // Do stuff
    DetectStudentItemDescriptionAndType(studentItem,
                                                        bFirstStudent,
                                                        iClass,
                                                        out string strDesc,
                                                        out string strType);
   // Do stuff
}
private void DetectStudentItemDescriptionAndType(MSAHistoryItemStudent studentItem, bool bFirstStudent, int iClass, out string strDesc, out string strType)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

I want to change `AddWeekToHistory` so that it can be passed a `DetectStudentItemDescriptionAndType` function. This is because I want to add a second version of that function that will use different logic (same parameters).

Ultimately I want to call `AddWeekToHistory(ref xdoc, historyWeek, [name-of-func]);`.

I understand from the answers that since I am using a `void` function that I should use `Action`. But I was getting lost in teh answers because the method in the original question there was passed a parameter and yet in the examples of running the passed function they did not actually pass parameters.

So rather than confuse an existing question I have asked a new one. What changes are needed for me to support passing `DetectStudentItemDescriptionAndType` and its variants (same attributes) as a function to `AddWeekToHistory`?

Comment: What exactly didn't work when you tried the implement the answers in the other question? By `attributes` do you mean `parameters`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delegates: Predicate vs. Action vs. Func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566860/delegates-predicate-vs-action-vs-func)

Comment: @Liam It's likely that the `out` parameters will be causing the issue. The `Action` delegates don't support them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use any of the `Action<...>` delegates for a method with `ref` or `out` parameters. You will need a custom delegate instead:

```
public delegate void DetectStudentItemDescriptionAndTypeDelegate(MSAHistoryItemStudent studentItem, bool bFirstStudent, int iClass, out string strDesc, out string strType);

private void AddWeekToHistory(ref XDocument xdoc, MSAHistoryWeek historyWeek, DetectStudentItemDescriptionAndTypeDelegate detect)
{
    // Do stuff
    detect(studentItem,
        bFirstStudent,
        iClass,
        out string strDesc,
        out string strType);
   // Do stuff
}

private void DetectStudentItemDescriptionAndType(MSAHistoryItemStudent studentItem, bool bFirstStudent, int iClass, out string strDesc, out string strType)
{
    // Do stuff
}

AddWeekToHistory(xdoc, historyWeek, DetectStudentItemDescriptionAndType);
```

[Delegates - C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)

Comment: There's currently a proposal to introduce support for `out` and `ref` modifiers on `Func` and `Action`: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/5321